# Organizing screen resolutions?

Tags: python

**Does it make sense to organize screen resolutions?**

I write a lot of selenium tests, often which I need to choose a resolution for the browser.  I ended up creating a dictionary with some of the more common resolutions I need to test, but I've never been happy with it.

```py
    DIMENSIONS = {
        # 4:3
        "1024": (1024, 768),
        "1280": (1280, 960),
        "1600": (1600, 1200),
        "1920": (1920, 1440),
        # 16:9
        "720": (1280, 720),
        "1080": (1920, 1080),
        "1440": (2560, 1440),
        "2160": (3840, 2160),  # 4k
        "4320": (7680, 4320),  # 8k
    }
```

Issues I have with this:

- references to a specific size requires using a string since variables in python cannot start with a number.
- dictionary lookups don't provide nice code traceability.

I figure I could use a letter in front of keys (e.g. `R_1080`) and then create something like an `Enum` or a `dataclass` but for some reason that didn't sit right with me either.

I can't decide if I'm overthinking things or if there is clearly another approach.

**Is there a better way to organize resolutions?**  Should I bother?

Comment: No idea if there is a better way, but I can't see a downside with Enums for each resolution name.  That would also enable you to safely and easily integrate over them.

Comment: How many places in your code are you referencing the dictionary keys? If this is limited then I wouldn't worry about this problem at all.

Comment: @PeterM I had the same thought. My trepidation is what to name a bunch of resolutions if not by the numbers. And if the numbers the the only obvious way to reference resolutions, should I even bother?  In some way, this post is a check against that assertion; to see if perhaps there is some way to catalog them without losing the the "meta" info.

Comment: @MarcelWilson Naming the enums after the resolutions means your IDE of choice will  know when you screw up a name (EG you type R_1025 instead of R_1024) and the mistake will be found at compile time.  Whereas if you use a string your dictionary will simply not return a value (EG you type "1025" instead of "1024") and that will only be found at run time.

Comment: @GregBurghardt it's more than a couple, but just barely.  Plus they aren't all in the same area of the code.  I originally justified the use of the dictionary because it was  pretty limited usage.  My concern is that limited usage will likely grow a bit as more devices and screen sizes are added.  This is indeed one of those items that I could leave well enough alone and be fine with it.  But I figured it was worth investigating a little.

Comment: @PeterM That's precisely what I figured as well. It's a no-brainer for a zillion other data sets, the only issue I think I'm having here is because these are pairs of ints.  Your comment made me realize trying to create vars for them is the right idea.  I'll have to ponder a naming convention that "makes sense".